# Using same locator on different pages (Python)

Tags: python, playwright

I'm doing something like this:

```
await PAGE1.get_by_role("button", name="mono").nth(3).click()
await PAGE2.get_by_role("button", name="mono").nth(3).click()
```

I've been trying to figure out if there was a way to set up a locator, so I can just write:

```
mylocator = .......
await PAGE1.mylocator.click()
await PAGE2.mylocator.click()
```

But I can't figure out if it's even posible in python... ??

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
# Define the locator
mylocator = page.locator("button[name='mono']")

# Use the locator on PAGE1
await PAGE1.wait_for_selector(mylocator)
await mylocator.nth(3).click()

# Use the locator on PAGE2
await PAGE2.wait_for_selector(mylocator)
await mylocator.nth(3).click()
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but  wouldn't that effectively click the button on page1 twice?